# Pass a variable in the html template in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I need to create an html django template a paragraph with a select dinamically created. I read values from a txt file and I store it in a dict, when I call the render to response I pass this dict but when I try to print its values in the template it doesn't print anything. This is my views:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = {
    'variable': 'This has been sent'
    }
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and this is the print in the html template:

And this is the variable I'm calling in the HTML template:

**index.html**

```
<p>Hey Dear! {{variable}}</p>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to write a [mre]. Currently the example you show should work perfectly, hence your problem is not _reproducible_.

Comment: Is it showing the Hey Dear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    def index(request):
        variable = 'This has been sent'
        context = {
        'variable': variable
        }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

in template:

```
<p>Hey Dear! {{variable}}</p>
```